# Problems with Transform-Broadcaster on custom Bot

Tags: navigation, amcl

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi Everyone,

i hope someone can answer me a question. I have a custom robot and i would like to use the Navigation-Stack of ROS.
i follow this tutorial: (http://wiki.ros.org/navigation)
The Problem is that anything is incorrect on my Transform-Boradcaster. The tf-tree is map-->odom-->base_link-->base_laser.

Here is my Transform-Broadcaster:

```
#include <ros/ros.h>
#include <tf/transform_broadcaster.h>

int main(int argc, char** argv){

ROS_INFO("starte tf_broadcaster!");
ros::init(argc, argv, "robot_tf_publisher");
ros::NodeHandle n;

ros::Rate r(100);

tf::TransformBroadcaster broadcaster;

while(n.ok()){
  broadcaster.sendTransform(
     tf::StampedTransform(
     tf::Transform(tf::Quaternion(0, 0, 0, 1), tf::Vector3(0.1, 0.0, 0.2)),
     ros::Time::now(),"base_link", "base_laser"));

     broadcaster.sendTransform(
     tf::StampedTransform(
     tf::Transform(tf::Quaternion(0, 0, 0, 0), tf::Vector3(0.0, 0.0, 0.0)),
     ros::Time::now(),"odom", "base_link"));

     broadcaster.sendTransform(
     tf::StampedTransform(
     tf::Transform(tf::Quaternion(0, 0, 0, 0), tf::Vector3(0.0, 0.0, 0.0)),
     ros::Time::now(),"map", "odom"));

  r.sleep();
 }
}
```

If i start the Ros-Navigation the last Message  is "odom received". All is ok!
So when i click on "2D Pose Estimate" the result is this:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/n211hzuvjrr4rdj/Screenshot%202015-04-29%2016.21.35.png?dl=0

The Odom-Frame and the base_link/base_laser-Frame are on two different places. Why?

if i still click on the button "2D Nav Goal" the robot rotates in a circle and i get an Error:

"Rotate recovery can't´t rotate in place because there is a potential collision. cost -1.00"

Here is the log:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/7d4fv3ad2h277at/%20log.png?dl=0

I think the Problem is the Transform-Broadcaster. Can anybody help me?

Thanks

Max

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/208191/problems-with-transform-broadcaster-on-custom-bot/) by [Twista3579](https://answers.ros.org/users/21669/twista3579/) on ROS Answers with karma: 31 on 2015-04-29

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

`odom -> base_link` transform should not be static as you are publishing .  Check [how to publish odom](http://wiki.ros.org/navigation/Tutorials/RobotSetup/Odom).

---

Originally posted by [bvbdort](https://answers.ros.org/users/9486/bvbdort/) with karma: 3034 on 2015-04-30

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Twista3579](https://answers.ros.org/users/21669/twista3579/) on 2015-04-30**:
many thanks, this solve my problem.  Navigation works ! :-D